What systems are available for landing on aircraft carrier?
Is the old and manual system of "Optical Landing System" (the "meatball") and the Landing Signal Officer(s) the only system for landing on aircraft carriers?

Since you're asking whether the manual system is the only one:
Operational on the F/A-18 is the "AN/APN-245 Automatic Carrier Landing System".

https://www.sncorp.com/capabilities/automatic-carrier-landing-system-acls-radar-beacon/

Also worth mentioning alongside this (ACLS) is ICLS, the instrument carrier landing system, which provides ILS-like glideslope and localizer-style guidance via HUD visual cues. In many implementations, that involves flying the needles manually, but in some conditions it's more reliable than the OLS since it doesn't require visual line of sight.

@Jules, reliability and line of sight are completely unrelated.  You still need to transition to the OLS to land off an ICLS instrument approach. (See my answer to the question I linked in comments above.)

@MichaelHall I meant, reliable in the sense of being available and usable in situations where the IFLOLS system from OCS is unusable because of inclement weather, as well as further out in the approach and landing pattern for a carrier. I don't disagree with the rest of your point.

@Jules ok, the wording of your comment came across as if you thought they were interchangeable and parallel vs complementary and serial.
